# How to put an image at the bottom of the page/everything else in HTML?

Tags: html

So, I'm an absolute beginner and I'm just learning how to make a website. I'm trying to put an image under the text "this i what i do" on this website https://20sparks.github.io/portfolio/

I just want to put the image under that

text, and make it full width, for example, 1920x700.
I've already googled how to do it but absolutely no code I found has worked.

I've attached the website's code so anyone can take a look.
I know I should use something like  to add the image to my webpage but I have no idea where to place that line of code and how to make the image go to the bottom of the webpage.

If anyone could explain how to do it in a beginner-friendly way, I'd greatly appreciate it.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    
  <body style="background-color:black;">
    <h1>hello</h1>    
        <style type="text/css">
      h1
      {
        margin:0;
        padding: 0;   
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
       
      }
          
    </style>
    <p>this is what i do</p> 
     <img src="daniel-leone-v7daTKlZzaw-unsplash.jpg" alt=mountains">
     <style type="text/css">
       p
       {
        margin:0;
        padding: 0;   
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        top: 120%;
        left: 50%;
        transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
       
      }
       </style>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide all the code? All html tags must have a closing tag as well, (except img,br etc.)

1. It looks like you are missing closing tag on html,head,body,style
2. You are missing the actual image

something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
The content of the document......
</body>

</html>
```

There are many ways you can have you image at the bottom. Here is one way.

https://codepen.io/lefter/pen/ExXgzXW

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I tried copy-pasting the <img src> line from your example however instead of the image appearing on the bottom of the page, it just ends up as a background image which is not what I want. I updated the code snippet so you can see the whole of the code that I have.

Comment: you need to copy css styles as well

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I need to copy both the codes you provided to achieve that result? If so, do i write the CSS code in the same file as HTML or where else do I write the CSS code?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to use the background-image property in css. You can add the property to the body element and an image should appear behind all other elements.

```
<style>
  body {
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1920/700");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
</style>
```

As a side note you can have multiple css selectors inside the same style tag. And styles should be placed inside the head tag.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        ...
      }

      h1 {
        ...
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```